# Hi how do i find the value and postion in an array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have this code so far, it prints the values but i cant seem to think of a way to get the positions..

```
public static ArrayList defineSeq(){

  for(int i=0; i<sparseRix.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<sparseRix.length; j++){

      int value =sparseRix[i][j];
      int postion // What do i do here to get the postion

      System.out.println("Value is " +value +"position" is +position);  
    }
  }
  return arrayList;

}
```

Comment: You are not actually finding anything here.  But if all you need to do is to print the content of the array, then you need to output `i` and `j` as a position.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  (In other words, what will your code be able to do once you get this right?)

Answer (score 1):

`i` and `j` together is your position. Either use an array to return it, or use the width of the original array to generate a value, like `i*width + j`.

Comment: cheers, any idea how to add the postion and value to an array list from an array?

Answer (score 0):

i*sparseRix.length+j if the top left is the 0th position

Answer (score 0):

if by position you mean the rows and columns for each value do

```
    System.out.printf("Value is %s, in row %s and column %s \n", value, i, j);
```

or if you meant position as first, second, etc.

```
   System.out.printf("Value is %s, in position %sth \n", value, i*sparseRix.length+j);
```

as stated above...

Answer (score 0):

Since you started with a 2D array, you probably can't have a 1D position to locate the values.

Your best bet should be to use a "structure", call it position. Then you can locate the element using position.i and position.j variables.